# nodejs http request in recursive pattern

Tags: node.js, https, cron, ssl-certificate

Hi I am trying to make a http call in a schedule. The first occurrence in the schedule works fine from 2nd occurance I am getting empty objects and undefined.

```
var https = require('https');
 var schedule = require('node-schedule');
 var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
 rule.second = 10;
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){

  var options = {
    host: 'google.co.uk',
    method: 'get',
    path: '/'
};

var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    // some code
    console.log('Expity date is ' + res.socket.getPeerCertificate(true).valid_to);


});
req.end();
});
```

The output is as follows , Why is it not working when run as a schedule ?

```
Expity date is Oct  5 13:16:00 2016 GMT
Expity date is undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some painful debugging found out that the request object uses an agent to initiate a connection and uses the previous established connection and doesn't request for certificates again. Hence the behaviour. To solve it use "agent" as an option and set it to false.

Modified code below.

```
var https = require('https');
 var schedule = require('node-schedule');
 var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
 rule.second = 10;
schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){

 var options = {
    host: 'online.hmrc.gov.uk',
    method: 'get',
    path: '/',
    agent: 'false' // essential to close down previous conncetion pools and make a fresh call.
};
options.agent = new https.Agent(options); // Initialise a new agent with options as its parameters.
var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
    // some code
    console.log('Expity date is ' + res.socket.getPeerCertificate(true).valid_to);


});
req.end();
});
```